# Include K2 tags in RSS feed

Tags: php, joomla-3.3.x, k2, tags

I want to show the tags, that are assigned to a K2 item, in an RSS feed.

I have added:

```
$feedItem->tags = $tag;
```

to /components/com_k2/views/itemlist/viewfeed.php

and then added:

```
$feed .= "          <tags>" . htmlspecialchars($data->items[$i]->tags, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "</tags>\n";
```

to /libraries/joomla/document/feed/renderer/rss.php

I get the placeholder in the RSS feed view of  but the tags aren't being show.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Having now spoken with the K2 developers, it appears that this cannot be done using RSS. It can however be done using JSON.  To do it edit this file:

```
components/com_k2/views/itemlist/view.json.php
```